# Perl: Adding semicolon (;) when block ends

Tags: perl, block

This question may sound foolish, but it's important to me to be 100% sure that I do the right thing, so I decided to ask it here although this.

I've encountered in someone else's code **if** statements, which their blocks end with semicolon (;).

I guess these semicolons has no effect, but I want to be fully sure about it.

So can you please tell me? Is there any difference between the following code snippets?

With semicolon:

```
if ($var) {
    print "hi\n";
};
```

Without semicolon:

```
if ($var) {
    print "hi\n";
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are completely equivalent if there is no `else` block. With an `else` block the semicolon is not allowed.

Comment: So semicolons at the end of blocks never have any effect in Perl?

Comment: The semicolon is not part of the block. It's part of the following statement (which is an empty statement, containing only the semicolon itself in your case). So it doesn't affect the block. Please note that `{` has many meanings in Perl, and it has a different meaning within `do { ... };' and `eval { ... };'. In those cases the block is part of the expression, and the semicolon terminates the expression. Another example: `my $x = eval { 5 } + 6;`. This example shows that the block and the semicolon are not related.

Comment: It depends on the type of block. Semicolons are required after `do { ... };` and `eval { ... };` since those are statements.

Comment: @friedo: They are not statements: they are merely terms that can be part of an expression. They require a following semicolon only if they are the *last* (or only) term in a statement. If you have, rather pointlessly, `print do { 6 * 7 } * 2;` then no semicolon is required until the end of the *statement*, and even then only if it is not the last statement in the block or file.

Comment: @Borodin A `do` or `eval` block by itself is an expression and a statement. Obviously expressions can be composed into larger statements. I thought my meaning was clear but I guess not. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($var) { print "hi\n"; };
```

is to

```
if ($var) { print "hi\n" }
```

as

```
print "hi\n";;
```

is to

```
print "hi\n";
```

You have two statements, the latter of which is empty. An empty statement does nothing.

```
$ perl -e'print "hi\n";;;;;;;;;;;;;'
hi
```